# Sources and References for Motor Selection

Tags: power-electronics, electric-machine

So, I was wondering if there is a book/textbook which discusses the issue of selecting the proper motor for a job. The type of it (induction, synchronous, DC, etc.) and mainly the nominal power of it.

I am at a stage where I understand the driving method for each type and I can design a proper driver, but I really have little clue on how to select the right motor.

I am not looking for a solution on a specific problem, but a general approach on how to analyze each problem and select the right type of machinery, based on the torque, speed and power required. I know that this is more of a "mechanical engineer" problem, but if anyone knows a source (no matter the size), I would like to know.

---

EDIT

Just to clarify: I am not looking for a way to decide the motor based on the requirements, but on a way to define those requirements. For example, lets say we want to choose a motor for a garage door. First of all, we have to know the way that the door opens. Is it on a rail and the motor has transform rotational movement to linear? or it wraps around an axis, as in "classic american garage door"? How much the door weights? How fast we want it to open? different gear boxes are needed, different torques and speeds in each example.

Comment: You could write a whole book, or at least a chapter based on selecting motors. But I have found that it is usually best to start with torque and speed requirements, and any special requirements such as ability to maintain high torque at zero speed, or ability to achieve accurate positioning (in which case you will need some type of servo system, so you need to choose motors which are integrated with a servo system).

Comment: @mkeith If the requirements are defined it's way simpler. You know the basic behavior of each type, look at the nameplates and decide which is the one for the job. My question is how exactly you define those requirements. I will edit my post, in order to clarify this.

Comment: If you do not know how much torque you need, you cannot choose a motor.

Comment: @mkeith Totally agree with you. But calculating the needed torque is not trivial, at least for me. I am asking for something that presents a method of calculating torques, speeds, etc. based on the load (garage door, automobile, industrial lane, etc.)

Comment: I think the question is both too broad, and after these clarifications, probably not really an EE question either. In general, there should be some way to get a rough idea of how much POWER is needed. For pumps it is pressure * flow rate. For garage doors it is force * speed. Etc. Then you consider the efficiency of the pump or pulley system or whatever. Then you have a shaft power specification. If you know shaft power and shaft RPM, you can solve for torque using P = T * V, where P is power in Watts, T is torque in Newton-meters, and V is shaft speed in radians per second.

Comment: It really isn't to broad. I ask specific for bibliography around the topic of calculating the necessary power in order to move/rotate a load. As for the EE part, I said that this is considered a ME topic, but I disagree with that. As EEs we must be able not only to drive the machinery, but also to decide with machine will get the job done, in a appropriate-scientific way.

Comment: I see what you are saying. It is a request for literature.

Answer (score 1):

In general, determining what is required to drive a machine is part of designing the machine. You start with the work being done. What is the mass of the garage door? How far must it be lifted? What is the friction force that you are working against? At what speed should the door be lifted? What is the resulting rotation speed of the shaft the the motor must turn? How does that compare with commonly available motors? What gear ratio is required between the basic mechanism and the motor?

What is the friction in the mechanism that converts lifting motion to rotation motion? Add the force required for lifting to the various friction forces. Convert the forces to torque at the motor attachment point.

If you can buy a motor with a gear attached, you can select based on the torque at that point. If you must buy or assemble a speed reduction mechanism, you need to add the torque required for that mechanism and determine the motor torque.

Some loads require additional torque for accelerating inertia. Some loads and drive mechanisms require overcoming a force or torque due to aerodynamic drag (windage).

All of this depends on the specific design parameters of the individual machine or mechanism. There may be books that tell you that aerodynamic drag and the incline grade of hills is important in selecting automotive traction motors but not garage doors, but what you really need is to learn the basics of applied mechanics and engineering problem solving. There are books and courses on those subjects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any in particular to suggest?

Comment: The books I have are Applied Mechanics - Statics, Introduction to Dynamics, and Engineering Analysis - An Introduction to Professional Method. All are more than 50 years old.

Comment: To the OP: For specific applications, it may be possible in some cases to measure things. Do not get so hung-up on analysis that you forget about measurement. For example, you may be able to insert a logging electronic tension sensor between a garage door opener and the door itself. That can tell you exactly how much force the garage door opener needs to apply. Getting boundaries on the problem is really helpful.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Thank you for your suggestions. I have Beer's Vector Mechanics for Engineers - Dynamics, which might be an appropriate book for what I am asking.

Comment: @mkeith has a good point. The measurement does not necessarily need to be sophisticated. A torque wrench and a fish scale or luggage scale can be helpful.